# Puppet iteration string/array

Tags: puppet

Can you think of a way to solve this problem in Puppet?

I have a custom fact with generates a string of IP addresses depending on the domain it is run on, it can resolve to have 1 to n addresses.

```
"10.1.29.1"
"10.1.29.1,10.1.29.5"
"10.1.29.1,10.1.29.5,10.1.29.7"
etc
```

I want to add these to the host file with a generated server names of servernameX for example;

```
10.1.29.1 myservername1
10.1.29.5 myservername2
10.1.29.7 myservername3
```

So how can you do this as puppet doesn't have an array iterator like "for each"?

Comment: Puppet now supports custom facts that are arrays, and since Puppet 4.0.0 there is iteration in the language and you can use EPP to write the inline template in puppet language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, even if you go about and use a custom "define" to iterate over an array upon splitting your custom fact on a comma, the result will be rather not what you expect and not even close to a "for each" loop -- aside of causing you a headache, probably.

Said that, I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but have a look at this approach:

```
$fact = '1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3'

$servers = split($::fact, ',')
$count   = size($servers)

$names = bracket_expansion("host[01-${count}].address")

file { '/tmp/test.txt':
  content => inline_template('<%= @servers.each_with_index.map {|v,i| "#{v}\t\t#{@names[i]}\n" } %>'),
  ensure  => present
}
```

What we have there are two custom functions: size() and bracket_expansion(); which we then use values that they provide inside a hack that leverages the inline_template() function to render content of the file utilising parallel access to two arrays -- one with IP addresses from your fact and one with host names that should follow.

The result is a follows:

```
matti@acrux ~ $ cat | puppet apply
$fact = '1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3'

$servers = split($::fact, ',')
$count   = size($servers)

$names = bracket_expansion("host[01-${count}].address")

file { '/tmp/test.txt':
  content => inline_template('<%= @servers.each_with_index.map {|v,i| "#{v}\t\t#{@names[i]}\n" } %>'),
  ensure  => present
}
notice: /Stage[main]//File[/tmp/test.txt]/ensure: created
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.07 seconds
matti@acrux ~ $ cat /tmp/test.txt 
1.1.1.1         host01.address
2.2.2.2         host02.address
3.3.3.3         host03.address
matti@acrux ~ $
```

Both size() and bracket_expansion() functions can be found here:

https://github.com/kwilczynski/puppet-functions/tree/master/lib/puppet/parser/functions/

I hope this helps a little :-)