# Puppet: Multiple files based on templates

Tags: puppet

I have several files which I need to be created by Puppet, all based on templates. As an example:

```
/etc/my-project/a.ini
/etc/my-project/b.ini
/etc/my-project/c.ini
```

What I would like to do is to ensure all these files using one statement in Puppet. Something like this:

```
define myFile {
  file { "/ect/init.d/$name.ini":
    ensure  => file,
    content => template("myProject/myFiles/$name.erb"),
  }
}

myFile { ['a', 'b', 'c']: }
```

However, this does not seem to work (inspired by [How to iterate over an array in Puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958114/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-in-puppet)). What am I missing there? How can I access the file name and use it, if not as `$name`?

Answer (score 5):

Your array declaration is fine, but you're actually trying to create multiple templates, all with a different filename `$name.erb`. You should change it to a fixed template name, like `template.erb`.

Another thing to make sure is that your template file is located correctly.

- If your manifest is in a module, the template should be located at `module_name/templates/template.erb` and called as `template("module_name/file_under_template_directory")`
- If it's a standalone manifest, you have to put the full path instead, `template("fully_qualified_path_to_template_file")`.

Finally, if you're still encountering errors, you should update your question with the error message so we can narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `${name}` instead of `$name`?

If it doesn't work, check that your template files (`a.erb`; `b.erb`; `c.erb`) are in the `<module_name>/templates/myProject/myFiles` directory.

If all of these don't work, post your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...it will serve your purpose in elegant way.

```
define myFile($file_name) {
  file { "/ect/init.d/${file_name}.ini":
    ensure  => file,
    content => template("myProject/myFiles/${file_name}.erb"),
  }
}

$values = {
            item_1 => {file_name => "a"},
            item_2 => {file_name => "b"},
            item_3 => {file_name => "c"}
           }




create_resources(myFile,$values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each |String $name| {
    file { "/ect/init.d/$name.ini":
        content => template("myProject/myFiles/$name.erb"),
    }
}
```

See [puppet docs on iteration](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_iteration.html).