# puppet array iteration how to?

Tags: arrays, iteration, exec, puppet

[How to iterate over an array in Puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958114/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-in-puppet/25676341#25676341)

// Assuming fact my_env => [ shared1, shared2, shared3 ]

```
define myResource {
 file { "/var/tmp/$name":
    ensure => directory,
    mode   => 0600,
  } 
  user { $name:
    ensure => present,
  }
 }
 myResource { $my_env: }
```

I tried this but $name got the whole array.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Facter `1.x`, all values that are returned from fact code are implicitly converted to string. In the case of arrays, all elements are conatenated.

As a workaround, you can make your fact do a proper concatenation, e.g. joining the values with commas.

```
setcode do
  result = []
  # ... code to store an array in #{result}
  result * ','
end
```

In your manifest, you can turn this back into a proper array using the [split](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#split) function.

```
$my_env_arr = split($::my_env, ',')
my_resource { $my_env_var: }
```

Array facts Just Work with Facter `2.x`.

Answer (score 0):

[@felix-frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3356612/felix-frank)

On the second line in your second code example, did you mean to use

`my_resource { $my_env_var: }`

or

`my_resource { $my_env_arr: }`

I ask because the latter makes much more sense to me, and the variable name would match what is shown in the first line of that example.